# How to change the DoubleClickSpeed for mouse in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, mouse

I need to change the DoubleClickSpeed programmatically.

So far, I've been successful in changing the Registry value:

```
 const string userRoot = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER";
 const string subkey1 = "Control Panel";
 const string subkey2 = "Mouse";
 const string keyName = userRoot + "\\" + subkey1 + "\\" + subkey2;

 Registry.SetValue(keyName, "DoubleClickSpeed", 900, RegistryValueKind.String);
```

Furthermore, I can confirm that the value has been changed by inspecting the "Mouse Properties" dialog in Windows 10:

[image]

The problem I'm running into is that despite the Registry value being changed, the new Double Click Speed does NOT TAKE EFFECT until I open the Mouse Properties dialog and click "OK". I'm guessing that the process of closing the dialog forces Windows to look up the Registry value again to make it active.

Is there a way I can programmatically get Windows to reload / look-up the DoubleClickSpeed value without having the user open and close the Mouse Properties dialog?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, figured it out. Had to use SystemParametersInfo and send a message to SPI_SETDOUBLECLICKTIME directly. This circumvents the need to alter the Registry at all.